# Capture git output into variable

Tags: bash, io-redirection, git

If I run a command in a subshell, I can collect the stdout into a variable, such as:

```
var=$(echo 'hello world')
echo $var
```

Will print 'hello world' as expected.

If I add colour and a new line, this too is ok:

```
var=$(echo "Text in \n\e[34mBlue")
echo -e $var
```

Prints "Text in Blue" with the word 'Blue' coloured and on the next line as expected.

However if I try this with git output, such as

```
var=$(git status)
echo $var
```

It loses all the newlines and colouring.

How can I capture the output of a git command and print it later on, while preserving formatting and colouring in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of [git's `color.ui` configuration](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_code_color_ui_code) is `auto`, which only uses colours when output is to a TTY. You can change that in your configuration to `always` to have the output be coloured regardless.

Most usefully for your use case, there is [a `-c` option to `git` that allows overriding a configuration value](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt) just for the current command. You can use that to set `color.ui` to `always`:

```
var=$(git -c color.ui=always status)
printf '%s\n' "$var"
```

---

Note though that in your second example

```
var=$(echo "Text in \n\e[34mBlue")
echo -e $var
```

it's actually the `echo -e` line that causes the colours to appear - the escape codes weren't interpreted by the `echo` inside the command substitution, and the backslashes and other characters were literally there. It wasn't that the colour codes were stored that time and forgotten when they came from `git` - they were created at the end in one case, and never at all in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bsh
var=$(git status)
echo "$var"
```

This is about bash quoting mechanism, without `""` quoting around `$var`, `newline` inside is treated as token separator just as `blank space`. [See bash manual for more info](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/516286/72456

Comment: Could you possibly _explain_ why this would solve the user's issue?